# Mongoid scope: how to check if an element is in collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following class:

```
class Team
  ...
  has_many :players
end

class Player
  ...
  field :gender, type: String
  belongs_to :Team
end
```

I want to create a `scope :girl_team` in class `Team` so that it will return all teams that has at least 1 player with "girl" as a gender.

I'm not sure how to do this.
I've tried:

```
scope :girl_team, ->{Where('player.gender' => "girl")}
```

it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would require a `JOIN`. However, there are no `JOIN`s in `MongoDB`/`Mongoid` (unlike `SQL`/`ActiveRecord`). If, however, you [embed](https://mongoid.github.io/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#embeds_many) `Player` in `Team` (which is unique/special to `MongoDB`/`Mongoid`), that `scope` would be:

```
scope :girl_team, ->{where('players.gender' => "girl")}
```

Another solution is to use two queries to get what you want:

```
team_ids = Player.where(gender: "girl").distinct(:team_id)
teams = Team.any_in(id: team_ids)
```